# Title and date in a calculated column (SharePoint Online)

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I need to create a calculated column with the value from the Title column and the date part from a Date & Time column, separated by a space and the date format like YYYY-MM-DD.

Something like this:

```
Title               StartDate            Calculated
Some title here     2019-03-13 08:00     Some title here 2019-03-13
```

Can someone please help me with the formula?

Comment: What have you tried so far? The community is happy to help you, but please share your efforts so far :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done, you can refer to below steps:

1. Create a new calculated column called "calculated date only" to only display the Date value of the "StartDate" column.

[image]

2. Create another calculated column called "calculated". Using below formula:

> =Title&" "&TEXT([calculated date only],"YYYY-MM-DD")

[image]

3. Then save you changes and your purpose will achieve. Please ignore the date format in the "StartDate" and "calculated date only" columns, I only did a simple test

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your suggestion. The first calculated column worked like expected giving only the date. I call that column "StartdateOnly". However, when I try the second column, I get "The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported.". I've tried:

=[Title]&" "&TEXT([StartdateOnly],"YYYY-MM-DD")
=[Title]&' '&TEXT([StartdateOnly],'YYYY-MM-DD')
=Title&' '&TEXT(StartdateOnly,'YYYY-MM-DD')
=[Title]&" "&TEXT([StartdateOnly])
=[Title]&' '&TEXT([StartdateOnly])
=Title&' '&TEXT(StartdateOnly)
Nothing works.

Comment: Directly use below in the formula: =Title&" "&TEXT([StartdateOnly],"YYYY-MM-DD")

Comment: If also do not work, enter the formula manually, do not paste. Pay attention there is a    space between " ".

Comment: No, sorry. I follow your instructions in detail, but get the same error. I've even deleted the column and created a new one with a different name. Same discouraging reslut.

Comment: You may add some more screenshots for helping me solve your issue. This should work that I have test in my Online environment. Also you can test this in a new list.

Comment: @imp.MSFT verify what Locale OP is using. commas might need to be replaced with semi-colons